# Passing localstorage using iframe to parent

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a site call example.com, and I have another site called something else, says it's example2.com. When I put iframe of example2.com into example.com, and do `localstorage.set('something',somevalue')`, will it worked? Can I access the localstorage somewhere in example.com/somewhere??

Comment: u should rather create a postMesage which will return the localstorage variable to parent

Comment: You can read about postMessage on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)